# sound bank for web audio api

Tags: javascript, html, web-audio-api

I'm using Buzz.js to play sounds on my webpage, but I cannot find a place to download sound files. Does anyone know where I can get a bank of piano keys, or any other large group of related sound files (midi would be great). Please help if you can.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could use one of these sampled piano packages from freesound.org
You just have to register, and they are all sounds under CC license.

I found these that could be useful, basically sampled keys from a certain piano:

http://www.freesound.org/people/Jovica/packs/669/
http://www.freesound.org/people/Corsica_S/packs/3957/

I'm sure you can find other packs with other instruments, to link to each midi note.

Greetings from Barcelona,
oscar

Answer (score 1):

Buzz doesn't use the Web Audio API. Please update the question title.

Samples are not a part of Buzz and should not be. You can find what you ask for if you go to www.google.com and type "free piano samples".

And, finally, MIDI files are not sound files, they contain instructions of how to play musical sequences, but no audio data. Consider it sheet music, if that helps.